# Incorect URL for file in OpenOffice using C#

Tags: c#, url, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer

I'm trying to work with OpenOffice Calc document under C# and getting an error "Url seems to be an unsupported one for network". My code is:

```
string filePath="serverName\\folder\\file.ods";
filePath = "file:///" + filePath.Replace(@"\", "/");

PropertyValue[] props = new PropertyValue[0];
XComponent oDoc = loader.loadComponentFromURL(AFile, "_blank", 0, props);
```

Error is raising only for files in network. When I'am using:

```
string filePath="C:\\folder\\file.ods";
```

Everything is ok. So I can't figure out how I should convert my path to be correct. Can anybody explain me?

Answer (score 1):

I find out what was wrong. The problem was that file was in folder name looks like "UserName#Files". Actually the problem is symbol '#'. When I replace it with '%23'(encoding to url notation) everything works fine.

**UPD:**

Better way to use System.Uri to convert path:

```
string filePath="\\servername\folder\UserName#Files\file.ext";
Uri fileUri=new Uri(filePath);
filePath=fileUri.Absolute.Uri;
```

Comment: As a side note, you should rather use System.IO.Path methods (Path.Combine, etc) and generally work with strongly-typed objects, just to prevent this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
string filePath="serverName\\folder\\file.ods";
filePath = "//" + filePath.Replace(@"\", "/");
```

Comment: I'm trying but this does not works to with same exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any reason why you are using `@` in the replace function, as `Replace` function replaces all `\` to `/`

```
string filePath="serverName\\folder\\file.ods";
filePath = "file://" + filePath.Replace("\", "/");
```

Comment: I'm trying but this does not works to with same exception.

Comment: Yes, tryed this. I'm using @ becouse \ - is escape sequence.

Comment: I know it is an escape `sequence` but whats the purpose of having it in `Replace`. You have to pass "//" to give the path. I don't think it is required

Comment: Don't understand what your mean. Code you posted: filePath = "file://" + filePath.Replace("\", "/"); will not compile.